# How can i make responsive collapsible?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I follwed W3S collapsible examples. ([links](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible_symbol))
I understand css and jquery in this sample.
I want to make responsive screen, and add this collapsible example.
But if screen width smaller, text are gone.

I think this is because of code

```js
content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
```

If i make screen smaller, text goes down like this.

[image]

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You will probably need to add a `resize` event and recalculate the scroll height once resize event is stopped. And for an easier fix you can just set the `maxHeight` to a very big number, like 1000 or something, since it's max height, if the content is smaller than like, you will have the correct height even in smaller screen sizes (Hmm, but this fix seems will cause some performance issue...)

Comment: And if you don't care about the animation, it's even simpler, just change that `content.scrollHeight` to `unset` or `initial`

Comment: thank you! i solve this problem with two way
1. resize done event 
2. display='none'

Comment: Nice, welcome to SO :)